# the Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

when I called any findAll method of JPA then unexpectedly that statement throws the error "could not extract resultset" and also say that "the xyzTable is marked as crashed and should be repaired" and then I have to drop the table or change the findAll method by manually SQL query. can anyone please anyone tell me why this is happening because i don't know where I used the findAll or other jpa method
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecbjE.png)

Code:

```
List<GetAllDispatch> dispatchDataList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<DispatchData> dispatchList =**dispatchDataDao.findAll();**


    List<String> invoiceNumber=new ArrayList<>();

    if (dispatchList.isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("no data found");
```

on the ** line I am getting the above exception

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definetely on the database side.
Try to repair the table using admin tool, e.g. pgAdmin if you using postgreSQL.
Or try to drop the table, recreate it and check code again.